# Python, eliminating lines within angle brackets with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script to assign grammatical categories to words in several text files. In each text file, I have file headers within angle brackets <>. Throughout the texts there are also additional lines with information such as time stamps, page numbers, and questions from the transcriber. I want to remove these lines. This is basically what the text files look like:

```
<title      Titipuru Supay>
<speaker    name>
<sex        female>
<dialect    Pastaza>
<register   narrative>
<contributor    name>

chan; payguna serenkya man chiga; 
<ima?> 
payguna kirina man, chiga, mana 
shayachira; ninagunan shi tujsirani nira: 
illaparani nira shi illapay 
<173> 
pasasha, ima shi kasna nin, nisha,
```

Even though there are the same number of headers in each file the other <> material varies, so I can't just eliminate specific lines. So I thought I'd try something simple like a re.sub statement that removes everything inbetween <> and including the brackets.

```
with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as file_in:
        text = file_in.read()
        re.sub(r"<.*>", " ", text)
```

I tried <.*> on pythex.org and regex101 it worked in both places with a test string, but not in my script (yes I have import re). I also tried other solutions like: `\<.*\>`

Am I just not getting the regex right or there something deeper here?

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Have you persisted the result of `re.sub()` somewhere? - it does not work in place - produces a new string.

Comment: I added a print(text) statement below it, and in the output I could see that all of the <> material was still retained

Comment: Try `text =  re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", " ", text)`. Else, please add  more text to test against.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that did it! A million thankyou's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you may have several `<...>` on the same line. In this case, you are much safer with a negated character class solution:

```
text = re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", " ", text)
```

The `text` variable, of course, should be updated as Python strings are immutable, and the regex is now matching `<`, then **zero or more characters other than `>`**, and then `>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK6dR5/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Well I did have the rep for that, but not anymore, I'll be sure to come back and vote your answer up when I'm back up to 15. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are *immutable*, meaning they cannot be modified, only reassigned. The `re.sub(...)` is working, but it's returning a *new* string. Try this:

```
text = re.sub(r"<.*>", " ", text)
```

If this still doesn't work, please give us more information about your problem

Comment: This is the solution I was writing out as well. You need to replace the line with something else, as re.sub is returning a new string, not replacing the string that was input.

Comment: Ooops, yeah I guess I forgot to have the text=, but I did that, and it mostly worked, I still have fragments of the headers showing up here and there, always with the first bracket:
. 
<14:46

Comment: @AlexR., could you provide an example where it doesn't work so that we could test it?

Comment: A comment given above provided an expression that worked: <[^>]*> but thanks to @Brian for pointing out a dumb error on my part, forgetting the text= part.